# How to remove something from a custom vector? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector, erase

I am currently making a vector class in C++ and am just trying some stuff out. I am not sure if this can be done without causing a memory leak or leaving memory behind and not deleting it properly. I have commented the lines of code that I have questions for. Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

```
void remove(unsigned int toRemove) 
{
    T* tmp = new T[maxsize];    // T is the datatype of the vector
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (i != toRemove)
        {
            tmp[x] = array[i];  // does this line cause memory leak ?
        }
        else 
        {
            x--;
        }
        x++;
    }

    delete[] array;     // is there anything else I need to delete?
    array = tmp;
    size--;
}
```

Comment: Is `maxsize` a `const`?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. What is array? what is T? Does `tmp[x] = array[i];` throw?

Comment: One issue I see is that `toRemove` is `unsigned int` but you iterate using `int i`. Another problem is you may leak if there is an exception in your code, such as if `array` contains non-trivial objects and `tmp[x] = array[i];` throws.

Comment: Needless to say, creating your own vector class in an adhoc manner just doesn't work out too well.  Better to get examples of how its done and study them.

Comment: It isn't clear what role `maxsize` plays, but it seems like it will be larger than `size`. In that case, the array will contain uninitialized or default constructed elements (depending on type) so it isn't clear why you bother creating a whole new array. It seems like you could just rotate all the elements after `toRemove` left 1 element in place in `array`. The reason you would make a whole new array is to have a smaller array. Another reason would be for a strong exception safety but since you use `new` and would leak if you had an exception, that justification doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: Side note:resizing the data store when removing an element is expensive. Just shift the later elements over to cover up the hole and reduce the size by 1. You're probably going to need the memory again later, so you might as well keep it.

Comment: @user4581301 I am not sure how to do that do you have any ideas?

Comment: @RohanBari no because it needs to be resized which I do in a different section of code

Comment: What is the type of the array elements? If they're pointers to dynamically-allocated data you may be leaking memory if you don't free what they point to.

Comment: @Barmar the element type is a template so it could be anything really but it's main use case if for strings, chars and ints or other primitive types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of realocating I changed it to do this and it works better and is better optimised.

```
void remove(unsigned int toRemove) 
{
    unsigned int x = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (i != toRemove)
        {
            array[x] = array[i]; // shifts the elements backwards 
        }
        else 
        {
            x--;
        }
        x++;
    }
    size--;
}
```